# Cómo puedo obtener el nombre de un archivo de texto?

Tags: python

```
fichero = open("pruebas.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
texto = fichero.read()
fichero.close()
```

Comment: `"pruebas.txt"`

Comment: `fichero.name`. Echa un vistado al módulo [io](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/io.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), del módulo [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), así puedes listar todos los directorios y ficheros de un directorio. Su uso es el siguiente:

```
from os import listdir

listdir("C:\Archivos de Programa\")
```

En el caso del ejemplo, retornará todos los directorios y ficheros de la carpeta "Archivos de Programa", de la unidad `C:` (en un ambiente Windows).

Answer (score -1):

Hay que mirar el path del archivo, en el módulo `os` existe la función `os.path.basename`
Aquí tienes como hacerlo de varias maneras
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323515/how-to-get-the-name-of-an-open-file/324326

Comment: `basename` retorna el nombre del archivo sin el path, pero el OP ya tiene está información en el "open".